# Word2vec compact models

Tags: machine-learning, word2vec, pytorch

Tell me if there are any w2v models that do not require a dictionary. So, everything that I found in torchtext first wants to know the dictionary [build_vocab](https://torchtext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vocab.html#glove). But if I have a huge body of text, I would like to have a model that works at the level of phrases. But I did not find one.

Comment: No. For a given word or a phrase word2vec needs a way to look up its vector.

Comment: If I create letter2vec and after that I create new vectors from letter2vec

Answer (score 0):

Every word2vec model requires a dictionary that maps an index to a string literal. This dictionary mapping greatly speeds up training because the training is completely integer-based.

The string literal values can be any length, from individual characters to phrases.